# How to find best/popular running routes in new city?

Tags: health, walking, urban-exploration

Interested to know what apps/tools people use to quickly and reliably find good running routes in new cities they visit, without having to do a lot of research (eg < 20 seconds would be ideal). Eg a running route search engine if such a thing exists, preferably one with real data as opposed to blogs with paid writers giving opinions (if hundreds of people regularly run a given route, that’s *usually* more reliable than one paid writer’s opinion)

I tried strava which was highly recommended but I think they stopped providing public running data due to privacy some years ago.

Not sure if google has anything. And new to running abroad so not sure what the ‘go to’s are

Comment: https://www.strava.com/heatmap still seems to be available.

Comment: You might also ask on [outdoors.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Strava Global Heatmap](https://www.strava.com/heatmap) is still available, though Strava users can opt out to having their data added to the heatmap.

[image: Strava Global Heatmap, Montreal]

In-app, you can look up Segments, which are user-defined running (or cycling) routes for which people can set personal best times or try to top the leaderboards. You can view them by location on a map or in a list format.

[image: Strava Segments, Montreal]

Comment: Having tried both now, I did not find the 'segments' feature useful ('segment's are too small to be useful - some are just 100m). The heatmap is excellent though, although (I think) it's only available through the browser, and only after logging into strava account (no money required though)

Comment: @user5783745 I use Strava for cycling rather than running, so I hadn't looked at running segments before. Most of the cycling segments I see tend to be much longer. But it seems in both cases they are along popular routes.